# Ubuntu doesn't recognize my hard disk

Tags: 18.04, dell

I have a Dell XPS 15 L521 laptop that was purchased in 2014.  It has Windows 7 on it, but I'd like to convert it to an Ubuntu laptop.  I downloaded the Ubuntu .iso and created a bootable DVD.  Ubuntu loaded from DVD, but when it tries to find a hard disk, it is not found.  How do I get Ubuntu to recognize my hard disk?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that windows is not in a hibernated state? If windows is in a hibernated or suspended state, you will need to properly shut down windows.

Comment: Newer Dell has drive(s) set for RAID or Intel RST,  that needs to be AHCI. Most also need UEFI/BIOS updates an dif SSD, SSD firmware update. Dell UEFI Dual boot instructions using Something Else
https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN301754/how-to-install-ubuntu-and-a-recent-windows-operating-system-as-a-dual-boot-on-your-dell-pc?lang=EN

Comment: I looked at the article and made the recommended BIOS changes.  However, Ubuntu still doesn't see both drives.